# How to discover which process causes always on screen, preventing blanking on timeout

Tags: screen

Ubuntu 20.10 on Lenovo ThinkPad P53.

Sometime, 50% of times, the screen never goes blank after timeout. It's like I'm watching netflix or youtube but it's not. Reboot fixes, but for few hours. More often the issue resolve itself, but again, for few hours.

How I can debug and discover why this happens? There is a log telling me why screen refuse to goes blank and which process caused this?

Comment: I have the same on my stationary box, but there, with power cable connected all the time, it is more of an advantage. Still, like you, I'd like to know the reasons.

Comment: first suspect is Slack Desktop app: if you make at least one phone call